# Formula result depending on the week of the day

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I've got a bunch of cells that have formulas to display the day of the week according to the date above it. (I'm using Google Sheets by the way)

I want the cell underneath the day of the week that has been calculated, to display a number (which is the number of stylists in the salon on that day usually) on that day of the week.  i.e if the cell above says 'Tues' then to display '5' and if it says Weds to display '4' and so on....

So row 1 is date, row 2 is day of the week (calculated by the date in row 1) and I want the cells in row 3 to display the number of my wishing dependant on the day in row 2.  I hope this makes sense? I tried the 'if' formula but couldn't seem to master it!

It won't let me add images, so here is the link to the master sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wqtMktTHcc1ldztyI_ctu58nPxRiUt6owaoOh1_KzjM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Show what you have so far and what it's giving you vs what you want

Comment: It'd be great if you were to [edit] your question and put a snippet of sample data to help illustrate what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry but I am a complete novice at spreadsheets so I can't be much clearer than copy the document and make it available! Sorry to be a pain....

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by introducting a separate sheet, let's call it 'Weekdays':

```
| Weekday | Number of stylists Site 1 | Number of stylists Site 2 | Number of stylists Site 3 |
|       1 |                         0 |                         0 |                         0 |
|       2 |                         0 |                         0 |                         0 |
|       3 |                         5 |                         3 |                         5 |
|       4 |                         4 |                         4 |                         4 |
...
```

The first column is the weekday (`0` is Sunday, `1` is Monday, etc), the next columns are the number of stylists available on that weekday, on the different sites.

Having this table, I can use a formula to match a weekday + a site with a number of stylists, from the main sheet. The following formula is for *Tuesdays* on *Site 1*:

```
=VLOOKUP(B$2, Weekdays!$A$2:$D$8,2)
```

The `VLOOKUP` function (check out [its documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?vid=1-635781824960635879-2068237842)) takes the value from `B2` (`Tue`, which translates to `2`), and matches it against the first column in the  `Weekdays` sheet. When it finds a matching row, it returns the `2`<sup>nd</sup> column - which is the *Number of stylists Site 1*.

Thus, the formula can be dragged across the entire row for *Site 1*, and it will adjust automatically.

For the other sites, you need to modify the last parameter of the formula. For *Site 2*, replace `2` with `3`: `=VLOOKUP(B$2, Weekdays!$A$2:$D$8,3)`, and for *Site 3*, replace with `4`: `=VLOOKUP(B$2, Weekdays!$A$2:$D$8,4)`

I have set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1od7P2aP2bz6ki3iP50ESzlNYUo_vBhMo2aEETP-F1Ns/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate this, feel free to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the 'if' formula but couldn't seem to master it!

If you want to use `if`, you would need to nest several of them one into another:

```
=if(L1="Mon",5,if(L1="Tues",5,if(L1="Weds",4,if(L1="Thurs",4,if(L1="Fri",3,if(L1="Sat",2,if(L1="Sun",1)))))))
```

I would use this instead:

```
=vlookup(L1,{"Mon",5;"Tues",5;"Weds",4;"Thurs",4;"Fri",3;"Sat",2;"Sun",1},2,0)
```

If your weekdays are actually numbers and not a text, the following formulas woould apply:

`=if(L1=2,5,if(L1=3,5,if(L1=4,4,if(L1=5,4,if(L1=6,3,if(L1=7,2,if(L1=1,1)))))))`
`=vlookup(L1,{2,5;3,5;4,4;5,4;6,3;7,2;1,1},2,0)`

Comment: I _think_ that using weekday names won't work, in the OP's spreadsheet that row is just formatted as weekdays - it is really a number, 1-7.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal - Thanks, I see that's true what you say. I've updated my answer, but I find your answer more practical.